# VBA: automatically run without a button

Tags: vba, excel

So I followed instruction and built a button linked with a VBA code and it works well. Everytime I hit the button, it generates new data in `Column C` by using data in `Column A`, `Cell B1`, and the VBA code. `Cell D1` is the sum of data in `Column C` and it will be generated automatically.

Now, I want to use build-in `solver` function in Excel. Namely, I want to find best `B1` value to maximize `D1` value. Is it possible? I think that means I need remove the button and make the VBA code works automatically to generate Column C and Cell `D1`. Can someone give me some instructions how to do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried to manually use Solver to do what you want? There are many examples on this site of setting up Solver using VBA. What makes you think you need to remove the button you programmed?

Comment: Check out [this article on using the solver in VBA](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/SolverVBA.html)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will check them out. These aside, if I want to remove the button and make VBA code works automatically, how can it be done?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by automatically. You can create a user defined function (UDF), but a UDF can only change one cell on a worksheet. You could also put your code in a [worksheet event routine](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx).

Comment: @OldUgly if OP want the UDF to change many cells, he can write it to be entered as an array formula